# Ruby on Rails access array in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

I have an array in my model but I don't know how to access it from some defs in this model

```
private 

topics =
[
'en','Sports','sports',
'en','Sports,Soccer,Football','soccer,football',
]

def self.load   
    topics.each_slice(3).map do |lang,tags,searchterms|
        load_data(lang,tags,searchterms) 
    end 
end
```

But when I try from to execute from console it shows an error

NameError: undefined local variable or method `topics' for Class:

I don't want to declare the array inside def because I need other methods from model can access to this array

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've defined `topics` as local variable but trying to get it as class variable.

Just change it to `@@topics` both in the definition and in the method `load`, then it should work.